# Cannot access folder via Samba

Tags: 22.04, samba

I set up a Samba server and added a first share to `smb.conf`:

```
[Staff]
  path = /media/see-admin/Daten/Staff
  available = yes
  browseable = yes
  guest ok = no
  writeable = no
```

The server and also the folder show up in Nautilus under "Other locations". When I click on the folder, the following dialogue pops up:

[image]

I 'connect as' 'registered user' and type in my user name and password. However, the dialogue briefly disappears and then reappears again. The folder is not being opened. How can I access the folder's contents?

**Update**

When I change `guest ok` to `yes` and click on the folder I receive the error `Unable to access location` `Failed to mount windows share: Permission denied`

The log file says:

```
[2023/04/04 15:37:35.141549,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:168(chdir_current_service)
  chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(/media/see-admin/Daten/Staff) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=65534, gid=65534, 1 groups: 65534
```

**Update**

`smb.conf`

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# We want Samba to only log to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd}.
# Append syslog@1 if you want important messages to be sent to syslog too.
   logging = file

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone server" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = never

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = classic
# primary domain controller', 'server role = classic backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 means that usershare is disabled.
#   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[Staff]
 path = /media/see-admin/Daten/Staff
 available = yes
 browseable = yes
 guest ok = yes
 writeable = no
 
 [sambashare]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
    path = /home/see-admin/sambashare
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
```

Comment: Did you set up a samba password?

Comment: Idon't think I did.

Comment: At first, may be, to see samba log files.  
And, then to try (temporarily) to open access for everyone, if your network is surely isolated by router/firewall, by changing "guest ok = yes"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've updated my question. I hope it helps.

Comment: Try following [all the four steps in this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview). 1. Overview, 2. Installing Samba, 3. Setting up Samba, 4. Setting up User Accounts and Connecting to Share . It looks like you didn't follow the 4th step.

Comment: Still not working. I had performed all steps before except of `sudo ufw allow samba`. I've added the entire `smb.conf` to my question. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Accessing `\\server.local/sambashare` via Windows11 returns `The network folder specified is currently mapped sing a different username and password. To connect using a different username and password, first disconnect any existing mappings to this network share.` If I click on the folder in Ubuntu, the user/passwd dialogue opens and nothing happens.

Comment: The log file says `[2023/04/05 08:41:45.092852,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:168(chdir_current_service)
  chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(/home/see-admin/sambashare) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=1003, gid=1006, 1 groups: 1006`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> [Staff]
>  path = /media/see-admin/Daten/Staff
>  available = yes
>  browseable = yes
>  guest ok = yes
>  writeable = no
>  
> [sambashare]
>     comment = Samba on Ubuntu
>     path = /home/see-admin/sambashare
>     read only = no
>     browsable = yes
> ```

Your problem on both of these shares is the Linux permissions on the path to the shared folders. THe only user that can access these shares is "see-admin". If you want to force the client user to use the see-admin user name you have to add that user to the samba password database:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a see-admin
```

If you want guest user access or any other registered ( meaning a user added to smbpasswd ) you can change your share definition to these:

```
[Staff]
 path = /media/see-admin/Daten/Staff
 available = yes
 browseable = yes
 guest ok = yes
 writeable = no
 force user = see-admin
 
[sambashare]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
    path = /home/see-admin/sambashare
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
    force user = see-admin
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That work from within Ubuntu. First step completed ... now user rights :D